# Why does the size of the jpg file reduce when we open and save an image using PIL in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Why does the size of the jpg file reduce when we open and save an image using PIL in python?

```
img = Image.open("Koala.jpg") # Size of the image is 763 KB
width,height = img.size
pixel_values = list(img.getdata())
im= Image.new('RGB', (1024, 768))
im.putdata(pixel_values)
im.save('test.jpeg')          # Size of the image is 142 KB
```

Comment: Is the original image larger than the size you are defining? In other words,  You're setting the size to 1024, 768.  Is that smaller than the original?

Comment: Also, the default quality in PIL is 75 so you'll likely have some additional compression.

Comment: This is the info i get : print(img.format, img.size, img.mode) JPEG (1024, 768) RGB

Comment: @MichaelMior How to set it to original size ?

Comment: @mohanakrishna *size* or *quality*, you can specify `quality=100` in your save call to save at the highest quality level.

Comment: @MichaelMior Thanks. It works. But still the size is lesser than the original. Not sure why. Now it is 680 kb.

Comment: Can you add add the actual image files to the question? [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

JPEG is a lossy format. The size changes because you are saving it with Pillow's encoder which is very likely different to the one the image was originally created with. Also using a different quality makes a difference.